# How Browser Handles Multiple clicks on the Action Button

Tags: java, rest, web, jax-rs

I am back again in search of a solution to one of the best online solution centers.

```
@Path("/user/service")
public class UserFeedService {
    String status = "status_idle";
    String errorStatus = "ok";
    @POST
    @Path("/register")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String register() {
       if (!status.equals("status_running")) {
            registerUser();
            return errorStatus ;
       }
       return status ;
    }

    public void resgisterUser() {
        synchronized {
           status = "status_running"
        }
        //code below
    }
}
```

The code above is a sample code of the restful service that I am working on which is being called from my vaadin application on click of a button.

Now what I want is that when a user clicks on the button the first time the web service is called and the status is set to `"status_running"` , in case the user clicks on the button again while the previous service call is still in progress ,the service should return "status_running" which will be displayed to the user.

But the code above always returns `errorStatus` and not status as expected on multiple clicks on the button.

So am I doing something wrong here or it is how the browser works, that is it waits for the first call to the service on click of the button to finish and then invokes

Comment: Hi peeskillet, i would like to make a slight change in my question. I do not want to hold this state for each individual user only , if  User 1 has invoked the service and at the same time user 2 tries to  invoke the service the beahaviour should be same as explained above in the question. although I am more interested to know that when a user clicks twice on the action button does the browser sends two separate requests simultaneously or waits for the first request to complete

Comment: if a button is meant to do something, it will do so as many times user clicks it. If the case it to prevent duplicate submission maybe after first click you should disable user input through that loader screen or disable button

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is that the `UserFeedService` is probably recreated on each request so the `status` property is a different, default instance on each request (i.e. it is always "status_idle" for each request). Changing it to `static` should result in the behaviour you are requesting.

However, **this is a very bad idea** to introduce some static state like this to a RESTful service. Not only will it be difficult to test and debug. If you really do only want a single "registration" to be able to occur at a time, it would be better to externalize the state to some kind of datastore.